# Cancel Runnables posted by Handler to Handler Thread in Android

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I am using `HandlerThreaqd` to handle blocks of code that needs a lot of time to run:

```
HandlerThread t = new .....
Handler h = new Handler(t.getLooper());
while(true)
{
    h.post(new Runnable(){ public void run() { /* code that needs a lot of time */ } });
}
```

It is clear that after a period of time there will be pending runnables in the message queue of the thread, so is it possible to cancel these runnables? has somebody tried to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can cancel a thread by this code:

```
h.removeCallbacks("name of your Runnable Obj");
```

Comment: Originally I thought that the `Handler` has its own queue, but after looking at the source code of Android; it seems that the handler posts everything to the `MessageQueue` which makes your answer correct